# Adding space between words while rendering the contents from a .txt file using JS/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to display the contents of my .txt file in a div. However, I want to insert additional space between certain words. I know editing the file system directly using JS is not a good idea. However, Is there any way of adding the spaces between the word at the time when it is rendered in the webpage.

My HTML :

```
<div id= "show-content"></div>
```

JQuery code :

```
function readFile() {
    $.get('data.txt', function(txt) {
        console.log(txt)
        $("#show-content").load("data.txt");
     }, 'text');
}
```

My Text file (data.txt) looks something like :

```
Blaine Nemec
Alphonse Smither
Lon Garrick
Rob Hennings
Erin Tatham
Stefan Stacks
Allen Dang
Rolf Aultman
Jeff Christenson
Mohamed Croswell
Ambrose Mina
Rhett Jahnke
```

The display list is coming correctly. However, I want to add some additional space after each name. If its not possible to edit the .txt file, is it possible to achieve this in CSS or JS/JQuery. I have searched several stack overflow questions related to editing files, but none was in   JavaScript and couldn't help me out.

**EDIT:**   I am trying to add 3 or 4 additional space depending on the font family, after each name in the .txt file.

Comment: However, I want to add *some* additional space: how many exactly? What is the purpose of this?

Comment: what's your line terminator?

Comment: After each enter the line should terminate. After each name there should be 3 or 4 additional space depending on font family

Comment: @sjahan the purpose of adding 3 or 4 extra space after each name will segregate the names from each other for better visibility

Comment: @UdG if I were you, I'd work on my CSS/HTML layout instead of adding spaces. This doesn't feel like a very good practice.

Comment: @sjahan when JQuery load a div with the contents of .txt file it will load the text as it is. How do you design CSS for each names , all of which are enclosed in a div.

Comment: @UdG I'd personally not use jQuery's `load` to perform that task. This is a "quick done job" with it, but if you have specific need, I would first read the text from the file, then split it on `\n`, then create one DOM element for each name so that it will be clearly split.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay first of all, you are making the ajax request two time. One in `.get` and one in `.load`. Use `.get` only, you can alter the test of txt variable like:

```js
function readFile() {
  $.get('data.txt', function(txt) {
  
    cont newText = txt.split("\n")
    .map(el => el + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;")
    .join("\n");
    
    $("#show-content").html(newText);
    
  });
}
```

1. Split string using `\n`
2. Add a certain amount of spaces
3. Join back using `\n`
4. Set the variable as `html`.

Answer (score 2):

You can split the .txt words with the .split() method and than stylize them.

Something like this:

```html
function readFile() {
    $.get('data.txt', function(txt) {
        console.log(txt)
        myWords = txt.split("\n");
        for (word of myWords) {
          $("#show-content").append("<span class="beautyWord">" + word + "</span>")
        }
     }, 'text');
}
```

Then stylize the beautyWord class in your css with something like margin-left: 5px

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are trying to achieve by additional spaces, but here's basic JS code for it.

```
//change number of spaces according to your need
//you can also use &nbsp for it
var EXTRA_SPACE = '    ';

function readFile() {
    $.get('data.txt', function(txt) {
        console.log(txt)
        var names = txt.split('\n').map(item => getElement(item + EXTRA_SPACE));

        $("#show-content").html(name);
     }, 'text');
}


//change how each individual name element should look like
function getElement(name) {
    return '<div>' + name + '</div>';
}
```

P.S. generally we use CSS padding and margin around the element to achieve that

Comment: If I dont give additional space between the names than it will be difficult to read each names. The space between each words will be constant. That is the purpose

Comment: @UdG are you trying to print all the names in a single line...?? or each name in next line...??

Comment: In single line with gaps between each name. I got my answer below. Marked it